# Infinite product is entire and has order 1/2

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that the following function is entire and has order $\frac{1}{2}$.

\begin{equation}
        f(z) = \prod_{k = 1}^\infty \left(1 + \frac{z}{k^2}\right)
    \end{equation}

I think this product is supposed to equal some familiar function in complex analysis but I'm not sure what that is. Some hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the sinc inifinite product. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function

Comment: $f(z^2) = \sin(i \pi z)/z$

Answer (score 1):

We can find the order without any prior knowledge

$$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac1{z+k^2}$$
$\sup_{|z|=r}|f(z)|=f(r)$, for $r\in (0,\infty)$ we have

$$\frac{f'(r)}{f(r)}\sim \int_1^\infty \frac1{r+x^2}dx=
 \frac1{2i\sqrt{r}}\int_1^\infty (\frac1{x+i\sqrt{r}}-\frac1{x-i\sqrt{r}})dx
$$ $$=\frac{\log(1-i\sqrt{r})-\log(1+i\sqrt{r})}{2i\sqrt{r}}\sim \frac{\log(i)-\log(-i)}{2i\sqrt{r}}=\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{r}}$$

Whence $$\log f(r)\sim \pi \sqrt{r}$$
therefore $f$ has order $1/2$.